# installing getchabooks using Propel and Slim

Tags: composer-php, pear, slim, propel

I'm trying to use getchabooks (https://github.com/getchabooks/getchabooks).
and i keep failing at completing the needed dependencies and running the project .

In order to get to know the code I also installed Propel and Slim, and set the appropriate settings.

I have read many tutorials and guides and yet, Propelorm won't work through Pear.

Is there anyone that can guide me step by step regarding cloning and running this project from basics?

The following site helped me wit
h Propel but wasn't helpful with setup (for the setup I had to use composer because pear wasn't able to install): http://blog.spooxe.com/blog1.php/2010/11/07/a-solution-to-install-propel-in-a-xampp-environment

I've seen that many pepole had issues installing through Pear but none of the suggested solutions helped me.
I searched and tried solving this for days using few tutorials, but that wasn't successful.
I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just reinstall the dependencies with Composer?

Comment: hi thanks as mentioned 
"for the setup I had to use composer because pear wasn't able to install)"

**Is there anyone that can guide me step by step regarding cloning and running this project from basics?**

i am using XAMPP as a testing ground
can someone post step by step with command line?